# How to assign a line of python code to a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting in python doing something like this:

```
plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
```

I am creating a lot of different plots this way and would like to assign the latter part to a variable:

```
target_plot_style = """label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth"""
```

In order to shorten the plot line to:
`plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, eval(target_plot_style)`, I tried it with eval and exec but it does not work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can use dict and nested list to work like this of course `""" """` will be considered string you can't work with variables like this :)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dict to hold those values:

```
kwargs = dict(label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
```

And then apply them to the function call:

```
plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, **kwargs)
```

Or you use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a partially applied function:

```
from functools import partial

p = partial(plt.plot, label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
p(xval_a_target, q_prof_target)
```

Or you create a function:

```
def p(xval_a_target, q_prof_target):
    return plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
```

Don't think in terms of creating source code and `eval`ing it on the fly.

Comment: The first suggestion, using dictionary expansion (** in front of the dictionary) is the simplest and most pythonic way.

Comment: @Syntaxén Depends. If you want to pass this function around to other code without requiring it to worry about `kwargs`, the other two are better.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to have the process a bit more standardized.

There are two proper ways to do so:

1. Save the parameters you want to pass additionally into a dict and pass that dict when calling:

   ```
   target_plot_style = dict(label=r"target", color=target_color,
       ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
   plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, **target_plot_style)
   ```
2. Create a wrapper for this type of plots:

   ```
   special_plot = lambda x, y: plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, label=r"target",
       color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
   special_plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target)
   ```

   or maybe

   ```
   def special_plot(x, y):
       return plt.plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, label=r"target",
           color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
   special_plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's example how to create dict with values you need. Then you can add **target_plot_stype to unpack dict.

```
def plt_plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, label, color, ls, linewidth):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_color = target_style = lwidth = xval_a_target = q_prof_target = 'value'
    target_plot_style = dict(label=r"target", color=target_color, ls=target_style, linewidth=lwidth)
    plt_plot(xval_a_target, q_prof_target, **target_plot_style)
```